# My picture is moving too slowly

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently making a kind of adventure 2D game project for university.
I have drawn an array of pictures(walls,floor etc) and then the movable hero figure. The problem: without the array the figure is moving fine but with the array the movement starts to lag hard. Is it my Pc? or is my drawing method too "heavy"? Please take a look:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class World {
public static int WorldW = 16 , WorldH = 16;
public SpielElement[][] element = new SpielElement[WorldW][WorldH];
public int[][] level0 ={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,1,1,6,1,1,2,1,5,1,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

public int[][] level1 ={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                         {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,0,1,0},
                         {0,4,0,1,0,0,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0},
                         {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
                         {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0},
                         {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
                         {0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0},
                         {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                         {0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,3,0},
                         {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
                         {0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0},
                         {0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0},
                         {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0}, 
                         {0,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0},
                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

public World(){
    create();
}

public void create(){
    for(int x = 0; x<WorldW; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y<WorldH; y++){
            element[x][y] = new SpielElement(x,y,level0[y][x]);
        }
    }
}


public void generate(Graphics g){
    for(int x = 0; x<WorldW; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y<WorldH; y++){
            element[x][y].zeichne(g);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Well the int array is to define which kind of picture I need to draw and 
i intend to first create all the Panels (SpielElement) and then draw them
Here is how i Draw them:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class SpielElement extends JPanel{
    int posX,posY,type ;
    BufferedImage wand, boden, tuer, schluessel;



public SpielElement(int x, int y,int z){
    this.posX = x*40;
    this.posY = y*40;
    this.type = z;

    try {
        wand = ImageIO.read(SpielElement.class.getResource("/img/wand.png"));
        boden = ImageIO.read(SpielElement.class.getResource("/img/boden.png"));
        tuer = ImageIO.read(SpielElement.class.getResource("/img/tuer.png"));
        schluessel = ImageIO.read(SpielElement.class.getResource("/img/schluessel.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public void zeichne(Graphics g){
    switch(type){
    case 0: g.drawImage(wand,posX,posY,boden.getWidth(),wand.getHeight(),null);
        break;
    case 1:g.drawImage(boden,posX,posY,boden.getWidth(),boden.getHeight(),null);
        break;
    case 2: g.drawImage(schluessel,posX,posY,schluessel.getWidth(),schluessel.getHeight(),null);
        break;
    case 3:     g.drawImage(tuer,posX,posY,tuer.getWidth(),tuer.getHeight(),null);
        break;
    case 4:     g.drawImage(boden,posX,posY,boden.getWidth(),boden.getHeight(),null);
        break;
    case 5:g.drawImage(boden,posX,posY,boden.getWidth(),boden.getHeight(),null);
        break;
    case 6:     g.drawImage(boden,posX,posY,boden.getWidth(),boden.getHeight(),null);
        break;

}
}
```

}

I hope u get what I am thinking by reading the code and hopefully see what is wrong. There are no Syntax errors whatsoever but its so damn slow. In the end added all of this onto a JPanel Board which is added on a JFrame

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
private final int BREITE = 700;
private final int HOEHE = 700;
Hunter Held ;
World Welt;



public Board(){
    super();
    Held = new Hunter(200,200);
    Welt = new World();

    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g); 
    Welt.generate(g);
    Held.draw(g);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        Held.posX = Held.posX - 10;

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        Held.posX = Held.posX + 10;

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        Held.posY = Held.posY - 10;

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        Held.posY = Held.posY + 10;
        this.repaint();

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

the Hero(Held) is drawn the exact way like the other images with its Coordinates beeing altered everytime i press keys and thus repainted.
I will refrain from further code dumping at this point. This is how it looks like in the end:
http://puush.me/account?pool=1468274

(Sorry no reputation yet)
The figure on Scrren moves on KeyInput but with lags...
This is my first question and i hope it is detailed enough. 
Sry in advance if my problem is stupid only started 2 weeks ago with programming in general.
Constructive critizism is adviced. sry for code Dumping...

Comment: Your link asks for login...

Comment: my guess is that you are redrawing way too frequently.  you probably want to update _only_ the key positions in the key pressed event and use a swing timer to update the display at some fixed refresh rate.

Comment: Don't repaint large amounts of small elements when you don't need to, for example, the world, it doesn't change that much. Instead, paint the world to BuferredImage and simply paint that in one step. Generally speaking, it's faster to single image, then lots of small images or graphical elements

Answer (score 0):

Until I saw you mentioned JPanel and JFrame, I thought it was an Android related question...

Anyway maybe you should draw them in a new thread, on an invisible canvas/image/cache, whatever... then bring it to front and draw another frame in background.

Sorry, I don't know how to do it with Swing, but I think that's how all animation frameworks work. In Android people do all these dirty work in background thread...